# Display all information in Table A if a Row with column account number match together

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables, `reg` and `trans`. `reg` table contains all my users registration information and `trans` table contains all my users debit or credit in formation. I want to display on each user page, their transaction history when they login into their page. So I tried using account number, but it is not working perfectly. I want each user to see their transaction history when they login.

Remember that `trans` table contain a lot of credit or debit transaction information or history with different users with similar account numbers.

```
CREATE TABLE `reg` (
  `UserID` int(200) NOT NULL,
  `Firstname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Lastname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Middlename` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Gender` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Dob` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Username` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Accounttype` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `identificationtype` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Zipcode` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Cityname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Accnumber` bigint(200) NOT NULL,
  `Amount` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `info` enum('YES','NO','','') NOT NULL,
  `Status` enum('ADMIN','USER','','') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

---------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `trans` (
  `id_transfer` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `re_ln` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `re_fn` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `re_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `re_number` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `re_amount` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `transfer_code` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `routine_number` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `swift_code` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Bank_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Bank_address` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `State` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Zipcode` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Pincode` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Transfer_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `t_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Statuss` enum('YES','NO','CANCEL','') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is the code that displays the information

```
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM trans INNER JOIN reg ON reg.Accnumber = trans.Transfer_id ");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td height="38"><?php echo $row['re_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Bank_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['re_number']; ?></td>
        <td>$<?php echo $row['re_amount']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['swift_code']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['t_date']; ?></td>
        <td align="center">
          <?php
```

Comment: I guess, you have done it already in your code. You just have to pass the user id in the query using session.

Comment: No, the account number in reg is not the same with the account number in trans. it is picking another account number similar to the one in reg but both are not the same. i have 3042325018 an account number in reg.Accnumber and  3042325026 in trans.Tranfer_id.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little a modification in your query and pass the session value. For an example, a rough one:

```
SELECT * FROM trans
INNER JOIN reg
ON reg.Accnumber = trans.Transfer_id
WHERE USER_ID = SESSION["userId"];
```

Comment: is not working please help me out here is my session code
<?php
 session_start();
 if($_SESSION['UserID'] == "")
 {
  header("location:signin.php");
 }

 if($_SESSION['Status'] != "USER")
 {
  echo "This page for User only!";
  exit();
 } 
 
include("conn.php");
 $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM reg WHERE UserID = '".$_SESSION['UserID']."' ";
 $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
 $objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
?>

Comment: Thanks you Chri85 and AT-2017 i have done that properly and it is working